# Drupal openid solution

Tags: automation, drupal-7, openid

I am trying to find a social login solution just like StackOverflow uses.

Currently, I am experimenting with [OneAll Social Login](https://app.oneall.com/signin/) which works great with the exception that my new users have to manually create their own accounts, wait for emails and then sign themselves into the site - I want that process to be handled automatically.

**Can anyone suggest an alternative to Oneall which will allow my users to select their social networking login option and then be registered and signed in automatically on my site *OR* how I might extend Oneall to do it?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Facebook connect](http://drupal.org/project/fbconnect) does exactly that for FB.

Comment: But I would also like to find a solutions for other social networks.